# How to access a Named Credential as a Guest User?

Tags: force.com-sites, namedcredentials, guest-user

I want a Site Guest User to be able to hit a page that uses Apex to do an API call.  However, if I create a Named Credential of type 'Named Principal', then that credential is simply missing from the list of available credentials when you try to grant guest profile access.

If I make it a 'Per User' named credential, then it appears in the list of credentials I can give access to that user, however there is nowhere I can go to set the password for that user.  Normal users can login and set it themselves, but a guest user by definition cannot.

How on earth do I do this?

Comment: The Identity Type is actually meant to define whether the API needs user specific information or not- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_define.htm&type=5

If your API needs to be accessed from a site, i'm guessing per-user is not really an option. Anything from Named Principal or Anonymous should work. Do you come across a specific error on your site ? Please post the information more specific to the issue to get better help.

Comment: The specific error I get is on the line of code where it tries to merge the password from the Named Credential into a header field.  It immediately gives the end user the 'You must be authenticated' page.  If I change my Named Credential to be a Named Principal then I cannot grant the Site Guest User access to it. It simply does not appear in the list.

Comment: Does your external service require Username and password to be supplied to it ? In that case it would be better if you use Named principal and add the Headers programmatically with fixed username and password values. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_custom_headers_bodies.htm

Comment: I could do that, but I was hoping to store the password securely in the Named Credential, rather than somewhere else :(

Comment: You can store a username and password with Named Principal some explanation here - https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/01/15/named-credentials-setup/

Make sure to check the Generate Authorization Header

Comment: This is the error you get if you try to use a Named Credential of type Named Principal as a Guest user: 12:14:23.0 (121684276)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: Script-thrown exception

Comment: Can you post the apex code that uses the named credential too ?